# Are trailing commas in Perl a bad practice?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

Today I was in a Webex meeting showing my screen with some Perl code I wrote. My boss suddenly told me while everyone else was looking and hearing that I had to remove trailing commas from my hash and array structures because it is a bad practice. I said I didn't think that was a bad practice in Perl, but he insisted and made me delete those commas just to show my script running in the meeting.

I still think it's not a bad practice in Perl, but I can be wrong. I actually find them pretty convenient and a good practice because they prevent me from adding new elements and forgetting to add the corresponding comma in the process.

But, I'd really like to know if it's a good or bad practice and be able to show it my boss (if he's wrong) with good arguments and even good sources for my arguments.

So, is it a bad practice to leave trailing commas?

This is an example:

```
my $hash_ref = {
    key1    => 'a',
    key2    => 'b',
    key3    => 'c',
};

my $array_ref = [
    1,
    2,
    3,
];
```

Comment: Terrible display of power abuse... and, IMHO, ignorance.

Comment: It's outdated, but [`Perl Best Practices`](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596001735.do) still has some good pointers: [`Code Layout > Commas`](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/perl/0596001738/2dot-code-layout/commas)

Comment: @Miller: funny that that code was clearly edited; the text implies the `)` was originally on the following line.

Comment: @ysth Aye, I noticed that as well.  Currently have my copy of the book on a shelf 20 miles away, so am not able to actually take it down to verify though.  Figured the words were enough.  :)

Comment: Those that can't do, boss.

Comment: The only reason to avoid trailing commas in Perl is that it may save you when switching to other languages, like JavaScript.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It's a great practice to have the trailing comma. Larry added it because he saw programmers add elements to a list (or whatever their language called it) but forget the separator character. Perl allows the trailing comma to make that less common. It's not a quirk or side effect of something else. That's what Perl wants you to do.

What is bad practice, however, is distracting a meeting full of people with something your boss could have corrected later. Unless the meeting was specifically a code review, your boss wasted a bunch of time. I've always wished that to join a video conference, you had to enter your per-minute compensation so a counter would show on everyone's screen to show how much money was being wasted. Spending a couple hundred dollars watching you remove commas on a working program would tamp down that nonsense.

Answer (score 32):

So the PBP page referred to by Miller argues for making it easier to reorder the list by cutting and pasting lines; the mod_perl coding style document linked by Borodin argues for avoiding a momentary syntax error when you add stuff.

Much more significant than either, in my opinion, is that if you always have a trailing comma and you add a line, the diff only shows the line you added and the existing lines remain unchanged.  This makes blame-finding better, and makes diffs more readable.

All three are good reasons for always using trailing commas, and there are in my opinion no good reasons not to do so.

Comment: I definitely appreciate this fact as well.  So much so that I find it disappointing when other languages don't allow the trailing comma.

Answer (score 17):

The Apache [mod_perl coding style document](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/devel/core/coding_style.html) says this

> Whenever you create a list or an array, always add a comma after the last item. The reason for doing this is that it's highly probable that new items will be appended to the end of the list in the future. If the comma is missing and this isn't noticed, there will be an error.

What your manager may have been thinking of is that doing the same thing in C is non-standard and non-portable, however there is no excuse for his extraordinary behaviour.

Comment: It's completely valid in C ever since C89.

Answer (score 7):

It is indeed a good practice and also mentioned in the famous PBP.

There is actually a Policy for perlcritic which always gets me: https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Policy::CodeLayout::RequireTrailingCommas

Answer (score 0):

I favor leading commas, though I know its rather unpopular and seems to irritate the dyslexic.  I also haven't been able to find a perltidy option for it.  It fixes the line-change-diff problem as well (except for the first line, but that's not usually the one being changed in my experience), and I adore the way the commas line up in neat columns.  It also works in languages that are white-space agnostic but don't like trailing commas on lists quite neatly.  I think I learned this pattern while working with javascript...

```
my $hash_ref =
  { key1    => 'a'
  , key2    => 'b'
  , key3    => 'c'
  };

my $array_ref = 
  [ 1
  , 2
  , 3
  ];
```

Comment: I'm not a dyslexic but that format certainly irritates me too. :-)

Comment: Code is most readable when most of it is written in the same manner, so when going from one segment of code one can keep parsing with the same mental patterns and keep up a good reading speed. Your code is different from the vast bulk of code (CPAN) out there and thus slows people down when reading. If your company has a large bulk of code like that, by all means, maintain consistency and keep it like that, but when interacting with the rest of the world, please be considerate and adapt your coding style to the majority. (There is no need to facetously accuse people of having real illnesses.)

Comment: dunno why the downvotes, it's a perfectly reasonable alternative to trailing commas.  better than no trailing comma, IMO.  of course, it is a matter of taste, and few would extend it to [semicolons too](https://web.archive.org/web/20091213153855/http://perl.4pro.net/pcs.html)

Comment: @ysth: I agree it's a reasonable alternative. However, it doesn't address the original poster's question of whether trailing commas are a bad practice. That may be the reason for the downvotes.

Comment: @Starfish while it doesn't argue they are a bad practice, it is the only argument *not* saying they are a *good* practice

Comment: Just like not having a trailing comma is undesirable because it makes the last line different, having leading commas is undesirable because it makes the first line different. You can't easily insert line(s) above the first line or move the first line elsewhere. The only reason to choose this format is to make the code look pretty, and that's a very subjective thing.